# How do I specify optional dependencies with a hyphen or underscore in pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I have the following section in my `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.setuptools.dynamic.optional-dependencies]
some_extra = {file = ["requirements-some-extra.txt"]}
```

However, when I try to install the package with said extra like so:

```
pip install -e "./package[some_extra]"
```

Then I get a warning from `pip`:

```
WARNING: package 0.0.1 does not provide the extra 'some-extra'
```

At the same time, it is also not allowed to use hyphens in the `pyproject.toml` key. I tried

```
[tool.setuptools.dynamic.optional-dependencies]
some-extra = {file = ["requirements-some-extra.txt"]}
```

but the key needs to be a valid python identifier.

What am I doing wrong?

Just a note: When not using a separator symbol, it all works fine, but I feel like it should be possible to use one.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that `pip` is warning about the lack of normalisation in the `extras` name.
This is a relatively recent deployment (in `setuptools`-years), mandated by PEP 685, and that has not yet been fully implemented in `setuptools`.

I suspect that a newer version of setuptools will automatically do the normalisation, however, as you mentioned, `setuptools` validation of `pyproject.toml` has not yet been updated to consider PEP 685. Have you tried to use the latest version of setuptools in `[build-system] requires`?

---

Another possibility is that `pip` wants you to write `package[some-extra]` in the `pip install` command.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I looked into your suggestions, but I get the same behaviour on setuptools `69.1.1`. I was only a minor version behind before.

Also, using `pip install "./package[some-extra]"` -with a dash- does give me the same result.